# Javascript check / uncheck checkboxes based on id

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have many server input checkboxes. I have given the first checkbox the id `all`. By default it will be checked. When the user checks other checkboxes, then checkbox with id `all` will be unchecked. And if `all` is checked other checkboxes will be unchecked. For this to happen i made the code but nothing is happening.

Here is what i have tried.

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" id="all" value="all" name="all" onChange="check()" checked/>ALL <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="servers" value="xampp" name="server[]" onChange="check()" />XAMPP <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="servers" value="wamp" name="server[]" onChange="check()" />WAMP <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="servers" value="mamp" name="server[]" onChange="check()" />MAMP <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="servers" value="amp" name="server[]" onChange="check()" />AMP <br/>
</form>


function check(){
    var all = document.getElementById("all"),
        group = document.getElementById("servers");
    if(all.checked == true){
        group.checked == false;
    }elseif(group.checked == true){
        all.checked == false;
    }
}
```

I wanted my code to work like [**THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/bGwrS/30/).

I dont want to use jQuery for some reasons. So i need my code to be in pure JS.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can't throw more than one element with the id `server` in your DOM.

Comment: i am generating this with php so i cant get them have unique id

Comment: group.checked == false; all.checked == false. You meant to do some assignment. Please modify it to group.checked = false; all.checked = false;

Comment: @Kishore You have to. Your page is invalid. You **can not reuse IDs**.  If you're using PHP, it should be *even easier* to assign unique IDs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use the same ID on multiple elements.

Try this, notice how I placed the checkboxes in a `div`

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/Sa2d3/

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div id="checkboxes">
        <input type="checkbox" id="all" value="all" name="all" onChange="check()" />ALL <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="xampp" name="server[]" onChange="check()" />XAMPP <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="wamp" name="server[]" onChange="check()" />WAMP <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="mamp" name="server[]" onChange="check()" />MAMP <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="amp" name="server[]" onChange="check()" />AMP <br/>
    </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('checkboxes').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var el = e.target;
    var inputs = document.getElementById('checkboxes').getElementsByTagName('input');

    // If 'all' was clicked
    if (el.id === 'all') {

        // loop through all the inputs, skipping the first one
        for (var i = 1, input; input = inputs[i++]; ) {

            // Set each input's value to 'all'.
            input.checked = el.checked;
        }
    }

    // We need to check if all checkboxes have been checked
    else {
        var numChecked = 0;

        for (var i = 1, input; input = inputs[i++]; ) {
            if (input.checked) {
                numChecked++;
            }
        }

        // If all checkboxes have been checked, then check 'all' as well
        inputs[0].checked = numChecked === inputs.length - 1;
    }
}, false);
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your request in the comment here is the updated javascript:
http://jsfiddle.net/T5Pm7/

```
document.getElementById('checkboxes').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var el = e.target;
    var inputs = document.getElementById('checkboxes').getElementsByTagName('input');

    // If 'all' was clicked
    if (el.id === 'all') {

        // If 'all' is checked
        if (el.checked) {

            // Loop through the other inputs and removed the check
            for (var i = 1, input; input = inputs[i++]; ) {
                input.checked = false;
            }
        }
    }

    // If another has been clicked, remove the check from 'all'
    else {
        inputs[0].checked = false;
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: this code toggles checkbox with all id i dont this. I want it like http://jsfiddle.net/heera/bGwrS/30/

Comment: can you make one more change. If all the checkbox is uncheck it should automatically check checkbox with id `all` @samer

Comment: in the example i gave if chicago and Texas are clicked and then unclicked automatically all will be checked. can you please update with this.

Comment: there is another problem. All is checked by default, so is there a way to disable unchecking it. Coz if they uncheck all there will be no results to fetch. Only way to uncheck all is by checking other checkboxes. I tried disabled property but what happens is total program stops working. Can you make this change pls? Sorry for asking more.

Comment: Here you go my friend: http://jsfiddle.net/c7jwN/ . I added lots of comments for you, but you can remove the comments afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can only assign the same id to one element.  What you want to do is give them a `class="servers"` and then use `document.getElementsByClassName("servers");` in your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have same id for multiple HTML elements. You could do something like this to achieve what you are asking for.

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" id="all" value="all" name="all" onChange="check(this, 'a')" checked/>ALL <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="servers1" value="xampp" name="server[]" onChange="check(this, 's')" />XAMPP <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="servers2" value="wamp" name="server[]" onChange="check(this, 's')" />WAMP <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="servers3" value="mamp" name="server[]" onChange="check(this, 's')" />MAMP <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="servers4" value="amp" name="server[]" onChange="check(this, 's')" />AMP <br/>
</form>

<script>
function check(cb, type){
    var all = document.getElementById("all");

    if (type == "a" && cb.checked){
        var els = document.getElementsByName("server[]");
        for(var i = 0; i < els.length; ++i)
           els[i].checked = false;
    } else if( type == "s" && cb.checked) {
        all.checked = false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: this is what i wanted. but the problem is i am generating this form with php. so i cant get them have unique id. is there a solution for that.

Answer (score -1):

put this function

```
function jvcheck(id,Vale){
 Checkboxesclass = '.group'+id;
 $(Checkboxesclass).each(function() {
    this.checked = Vale;
});

}
```

and then put this code in your main checkbox

```
jvcheck('group222',this.checked);
```

all checkbox with class group222 now checked .