# jQuery - Uncheck checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I thought this was supposed to be easy. There are a lot of answers on here about unchecking checkboxes using jQuery but when I try them they don't seem to work. I want to uncheck them as part of my function for resetting the form.

I have a loop and I create checkboxes inside it:
`<input type="checkbox" name="is_chosen[]" value="{{ $sample->id }}" class="flat">`

Here is the my code for unchecking checkboxes (not all checkboxes are checked initially):

```
$('input:checkbox').each(function () {
  if(this.checked) {
    $(this).attr('checked', false);
  }
});
```

I have also tried replacing `attr` with `prop`. I have also tried using just `$(input:checkbox).prop('checked', false);`. I have tried others more but they don't work. What am I missing?

Comment: It should `$(input:checkbox).prop('checked', false);`. If it doesn't work check what `$(input:checkbox)` selects.

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lk12nvjz/) check the demo it works

Comment: [Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915065/javascript-check-uncheck-checkboxes-based-on-id) Hope it will help :)

Comment: You don't need to loop . Just use $(":checked").attr('checked', false); as in my answer

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience guys. 

I found out that the problem was `class="flat"` (from Bootstrap), although I don't know why exactly. I became worried because none of your answers were working. Then I thought of removing the class. When the class was there, all the checked checkboxes were still checked after executing the function. When I removed the class, the checkboxes became unchecked after performing the function. I tried your answers again and they worked. I tried the code that I posted too and it worked. 

(Btw, do I have to post this as an answer?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry for the inconvenience guys.

I found out that the problem was `class="flat"` (from Bootstrap), although I don't know why exactly. I became worried because none of your answers were working. Then I thought of removing the class. When the class was there, all the checked checkboxes were still checked after executing the function. When I removed the class, the checkboxes became unchecked after performing the function. I tried your answers again and they worked. I tried the code that I posted too and it worked. So it was the class all along.

Answer (score 13):

You don't need to use `each()`. You can do it like following.

```
$('input:checkbox:checked').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: using the .attr() function didn't work for me but the .prop() function did

Answer (score 2):

It does work: https://jsfiddle.net/bfqew4du/

```
setInterval(function(){
  $('input:checkbox').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('checked', !this.checked);
  });
},1000);
```

Be sure that you are running the javascript after the DOM loads.

Comment: Loop is not required here as it can be accomplished with  $(":checked").attr('checked', false);

Comment: Loop or not is hardly the issue though @ArunSharma. This answered the question.

Comment: @Mackan It's not only about answering the question. Your code got to be clean, clear and to the point. setInterval and .each are useless chunks of code here.

Comment: What if he cleaned the code down to these lines for stackOverflow sake but needs forEach logic in his app? This is still 100% valid.

Comment: @ArunSharma I agree, but the most important part is answering the question, and both you and the other answer fail to do that.

Comment: @ Mackan. I have successfully answered it. Please roll your eye balls to the posted answer.

Comment: The question was essentially "why isn't this working". Showing a more concise way to do the same thing is not answering any question. Please roll your eyeballs to stackOverflow best practices.

Comment: @tommybananas: Its one banana problem. Let's stop kicking up the fuss. But inefficient code and poor use of functions is not one of the developer's best practices.

Comment: It's not inefficient code if it was stripped down...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to loop, it can be achieved with a single line of code: Use  `$(":checked").attr('checked', false);`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":checked").attr('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to apply a unique class name to the dynamic elements, so that they all can be selected using this class name. So while generating you can append the checkbox with a class name

```
...append('<input type="checkbox" name="is_chosen[]" value="1" class="flat dynmc-check">');
```

then use this class `dynmc-check` to select these checkboxes:

```
$('.dynmc-check')
```

Using this selector you perform the required actions, e.g. reset checkbox:

```
$('.dynmc-check').removeAttr('checked');
```

or count the checked ones:

```
var checkCount = $('.dynmc-check:checked').length;
```

See [this working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfqew4du/1/) for detail.